# Cortana always shows error like "error": "Bot service failed with status code: NotFound"

Tags: botframework, cortana

I am using Azure Bot framework, when I am testing my code it is working fine with web chat but Cortana throws the error :  "error": "Bot service failed with status code: NotFound". It was working fine till yesterday until I had not pushed the updated code to Azure. It is still working fine with Web chat but not with Cortana anymore.

I have already taken into account - the none intent coming from LUIS.

I am using Node JS v4.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for this.

There is a service issue presently where if you change the messaging endpoint its not picked up by Cortana services.  (It still uses the old endpoint.)  Microsoft is working to fix the issue.

Comment: Should be available now.